# How to test every value of a dataframe and fill specifc columns in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, iteration

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df <- data.frame(Class = c('A', 'B', 'C'),
                 V1 = c('21, 23', NA, '50, 100'),
                 V2 = c(NA, NA, '13'),
                 V3 = c(NA, '152', '18, 182'))
df[, c(2:4)] <- as.character(df[, c(2:4)])
str(df)
```

I setted up the variables V1, V2 and V3 as character:

```
df[, c(2:4)] <- as.character(df[, c(2:4)])
```

I'd like to test each variable to count the number of occurrences of values below 80, between 80 and 110, and above 110.
After, save these counts no new variables.
It should return something like that:

```
df <- data.frame(Class = c('A', 'B', 'C'),
                 V1 = c('21, 23', NA, '50, 100'),
                 V2 = c(NA, NA, '13'),
                 V3 = c(NA, '152', '18, 182'), 
                 BELOW = c(2, 0, 3),
                 BETWEEN = c(0, 0, 1),
                 ABOVE = c(0, 1, 1))
```

How could I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code does what you want, assuming your Numbers are always split by a comma:

```
df[, c(2:4)] <- lapply(df[,2:4], as.character)
newDF <- cbind(df[,2:4],t(apply(df[,2:4],1,function(row)
  {
  row.vec <- na.omit(unlist(row))
  l.Num <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(row.vec,",\\s?"),as.numeric))
  below <- length(which(l.Num < 80))
  between <- length(which(l.Num >= 80 & l.Num < 110))
  above <- length(which(l.Num > 110))
  return(c(BELOW=below,BETWEEN=between,ABOVE=above))
})))
```